# How do I know if this line passes the origin?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm studying representation of complex numbers in the complex plan. You know that the general equation of lines and circunferences is

$\lambda |z|^2+az+ \overline{az} + \mu = 0$

And when $\lambda$ is zero we have a line.

So we need to represent the following condition in the complex plane:

$Im(\frac{z-a}{z-b})=0$
With $a$ different than $b$.

We immediately know that $z \neq b$.

After further development of our expression we get to:

$(\overline{a} - \overline{b}) z - (a-b)\overline{z} + a\overline{b} - \overline{a}b = 0 $

Now I understand that, of course, this describes a line. 
For representing the line we need two points in which she obviously passes. Those points are the complex numbers $a$ and $b$. But because we already defined that $z \neq b$ we need to leave a hole in that point.

Everything seems fine to me until this point. But now I have a question:

- Does this line passes the origin?

I know that for the line to pass the origin $\mu$ needs to be zero.

But how can I define in this equation my $\mu$? It needs to be a real number, for sure, so we can't make $\mu =  a\overline{b} - \overline{a}b$ can we? $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers!

I'm really confused about this? Can someone clarify me please?

Answer (score 1):

You simply need the full line to pass by the origin, which is the same as $\arg a=\arg b$.

If $a$ and $b$ are given in  the form $x+iy$, it is also equivalent the 2×2 determinant of the real and imaginary part of $a$ and $b$ is $0$.